# How to dynamically set or execute middlewares for a page the right way in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, middleware, nuxtjs3

This is probably the wrong way, but it explains the idea:

```js
// middleware/some-middleware.ts
import otherMiddleware from "@/middleware/other-middleware"
import other2Middleware from "@/middleware/other2-middleware"
import other3Middleware from "@/middleware/other2-middleware"

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
  if(to.meta.layout === "member") {
    await otherMiddleware(to, from)
    await other2Middleware(to, from)
  } else {
    await other3Middleware(to, from)
  }

})
```

Or like this would be nice, but doesn't work either:

```js
definePageMeta({
  middleware: (to) => {
    if(to.meta.layout === "member") {
      return ["otherMiddleware", "other2Middleware"]
     } else {
      return ["other3Middleware"]
  } 
})
```